# Tokenize don't to dont using NLTK Python

Tags: python, nltk

When I use:

```
nltk.word_tokenize("don't")
```

I get

```
["do", "n't"]
```

What I want is:

```
["dont"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [TweetTokenizer](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.casual)

```
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer

tweet_tokenizer = TweetTokenizer()
sen = "don't won't can't"

res = [x.replace("'", '') for x in tweet_tokenizer.tokenize(sen)]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['dont', 'wont', 'cant']
```